# Можно ли самому писать магические методы в Python?

Tags: python

Читаю книгу "Чистый Python". Там говорится о том, что свои магические методы не рекомендуется писать из-за возможной несовместимости с будущими версиями языка. Как быть, если на всяких Хабрах и прочих находятся статьи, которые доказывают обратное, при этом ссылок на литературу не дают. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать. По возможности, с примерами и серьёзными источниками, стоит ли писать кастомные методы или нет.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под фразой «писать свои магические методы»? Я немного полистал книгу — в ней такой формулировки нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот что говорит [документация](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) `Python`

> *****
> System-defined names, informally known as “dunder” names. These names are defined by the interpreter and its implementation (including the standard library). Current system names are discussed in the Special method names section and elsewhere. More will likely be defined in future versions of Python. Any use of ***** names, in any context, that does not follow explicitly documented use, is subject to breakage without warning.

Перевод на русский:

> __ * __
> Системно определенные имена, неофициально известные как «магические» имена. Эти имена определяются интерпретатором и его реализацией (включая стандартную библиотеку). Текущие имена систем обсуждаются в разделе «Имена специальных методов» и в других местах. Скорее всего, будет определено в будущих версиях Python. Любое использование имен __ * __ в любом контексте, которое не следует явно документированному использованию, может быть нарушено без предупреждения.

Можно сделать вывод, что создавать свои "магические" методы не рекомендуется.

Comment: В тексте вопроса нет слова «создавать». Из-за этого возникает подозрение, что вы и автор вопроса говорите о разных вещах

Comment: Нет, я как раз это и имел в виду. Большое спасибо за ответ

Comment: @DarkSpace **создавать** магические методы в принципе никак невозможно, это внутренняя деталь реализации питона. Если просто добавить подчёркивания к произвольному названию метода — метод от этого не станет магическим. Так что кто-то из нас чего-то явно не понимает

Comment: @andreymal подозреваю, что речь идет о чем-то вроде этого https://stackoverflow.com/a/54560263/12788763

Comment: @n1tr0xs тем не менее это тоже не магический метод, просто вызов метода со странным именем. Заменить `__logging__` на какое-нибудь `do_logging` — и по сути ничего не поменяется